# Send button causes error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have just added a Like/Send button combo to my website. The Like button works. However the Send button displays the following error:

We encountered the following error when sending your message:

```
Requires a public email address: To send to an email address, first set up your 
own <a href="/messages/?setup" 
target="_blank">facebook.com email address</a>.
```

[This has been reported before](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302953569717849/?browse=search_4efe7536ed3d75691322564) and the response last November was:

> The behaviour here is correct, but the error message is
>   not being displayed correctly, this bug will remain open until the
>   error message is fixed.

[ The error message still has not been fixed to display as a link the to facebook.com email address and, as was pointed out before, the message is so brief that it is almost impossible to react to. ( about 2 seconds ) ]

So this means that anyone that does not have a facebook email address can not send a message. Fine, the button does not display unless they are logged into facebook, but this leads to an other issue.

If someone wants to set up a facebook email address, how do they do that?

If I go to Settings=> Gen => Email=> Edit => Facebook Email Active Facebook Email; I get redirected to my Wall.

If I go to http://www.facebook.com/about/messages/ and click "Go to Messages" I end up at my Wall.

( In fact I find myself at the Wall a lot. While researching the social plugin possibilities I wanted to get a app id, but any link such as "developer" or "developers community" => Apps: sent me to my Wall. )

I can not find any way for anybody to set up email.

Comment: Do you have a validated account (using phone/txt message)?

Comment: It is relevant, or how else will Facebook assign you a facebook email address?  It's one of the requirements for them assigning you one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug as reported on the Facebook Dev Site: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302953569717849?browse=search_4f6a3c45757ed3214987830